# Compare items in two separate lists in f#

Tags: list, f#, compare

This is the example I'm working on:

```
    let test =
  [("Andy", ["d"; "a"; "d"; "c"; "b"; "d"; "c"; "a"; "a"; "c"; "a"; "d"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "e"]);
   ("Harry", ["b"; "d"; "c"; "b"; "c"; "b"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "b"; "d"; "d"; "a"; "c"; "b"; "e"]);

let answers = ["b"; "a"; "a"; "c"; "d"; "d"; "c"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "a"; "d"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "e"]);
```

I'm trying to use list.map to compare each persons test and determine how many answers they got right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use the map-function? The result should be a number for each person in which case reduce or fold seems more appropriate.

Comment: I've given up on using list.map and now am using a loop.

`(fun counter pupilChoice correctAnswer -> 
                if pupilChoice = correctAnswer then 
                    counter + 1 
                else counter)`

I can get that far before I start running into problems. I know I need to do a do loop before that to run through all the answers.

Comment: You don't need loops. Lee's answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

I would create a function to calculate the score given a list of answers and the correct answers, then apply that to each tuple in your list:

```
let getScore ans correct = List.map2 (=) ans correct |> List.filter id |> List.length
let getCorrect l = l |> List.map (fun (name, ans) -> (name, getScore ans answers))
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution. You could even make `answers` local to `getScore` and use function composition to shorten it a bit ([example on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BymBGf1J)).

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
let test =
  [("Andy", ["d"; "a"; "d"; "c"; "b"; "d"; "c"; "a"; "a"; "c"; "a"; "d"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "e"]);
   ("Harry", ["b"; "d"; "c"; "b"; "c"; "b"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "b"; "d"; "d"; "a"; "c"; "b"; "e"]); ]

let answerKey = ["b"; "a"; "a"; "c"; "d"; "d"; "c"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "a"; "d"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "e"];

let score answerKey answers =
    List.zip answerKey answers
    |> List.sumBy (fun (key, answer) ->
        if key = answer then 1 else 0)

let results =
    test
    |> List.map (fun (name, answers) ->
        name, score answerKey answers)
```

If you put this into F# Interactive, the results will be:

```
val results : (string * int) list = [("Andy", 12); ("Harry", 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a little bit with getting both good and wrong answer count this will work...

First [map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370378.aspx) the results to handle each individual scorelist. Then [fold2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340290.aspx) with the correct awnserlist to find [matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) (you could use a simple if then here). I count the number of good and wrong answers in a [tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx).  The show function does a simple [iter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340469.aspx) to get the fist and second item from the tuple and then [printf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560.aspx) the values.

```
   let scores results corr = 
    results
    |> List.map ( 
        fun (name, score) -> 
            (name, List.fold2 (
                fun s rhs lhs ->  
                    match s with
                    | (good, wrong) when rhs=lhs -> ( good + 1 , wrong) 
                    | (good, wrong) -> ( good, wrong + 1)
                                ) (0, 0) score corr
            ) 
        )


let show scorelist = 
scorelist
|> List.iter 
    ( fun i -> 
         match i with
         | (name, score) -> 
            match score with
            | (good, wrong) ->
                    printf "%s correct: %d wrong: %d \r\n" 
                     name
                     good 
                     wrong
     )
```

run from F# interactive:

```
show (scores test answers);;
Andy correct: 12 wrong: 4 
Harry correct: 5 wrong: 11
```